# Como faço para fixar o value "pesquisado" em input com RainTPL

Tags: html, formulário, framework

Estou mudando meu projeto para RainTPL e não achei nada na documentação deles sobre isso.

Antes eu usava da seguinte forma:

`<form method="POST" class="row py-4" action="">`

```
<?php
$nome = (!empty($_POST['nome'])) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$telefone = (!empty($_POST['telefone'])) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
?>

<input type="text" class="col-3 form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo htmlentities($nome); ?>">
<input type="text" class="col-3 form-control" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" value="<?php echo htmlentities($telefone); ?>">
```

Como usaria isso com RainTPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário que você informe uma variável para o RainTPL para usá-la no formulário. Por exemplo: variável "user".

O código HTML ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" class="col-3 form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="{$user.nome}">
<input type="text" class="col-3 form-control" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" value="{$user.telefone}">
```